# add subview to a view controller from another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I have two view controller classes. On the first, I have an image view and on second view controller there is a text view. The second view controller has a done-button, on clicking done-button I want to add a label on the first view controller's image and pass text view's text on that label.
Is there any way to do it? 
Please suggest me.

Comment: Do you present the view controller that you want to control from the first one?

Comment: Do you have vc1 that present vc2. you get some value from vc2 and you wonna pass it to vc1?

Comment: on vc2 i have a button. On that button click i want to create a label on vc1 and pass value on that label which i got from vc2.

Comment: I edited the code check it out

Answer (score 0):

Use delegates. Create a protocol on the Second view controller
and make the First view controller its delegate. Use delegate methods to send the textview's text as message to the delegate (or in general, send any kind of data between classes).

Comment: Yeah it won't work if the delegate is not properly set. Check if your delegate is `nil` which most probably will be.

Comment: please suggest something else i really got tired of it now.

Comment: It is how it should be done. Create a protocol that notifies the other view controller when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the second view controller in the first view controller.

Call a public function in the second view controller from the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

View Controller A:

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
{
@public
    NString *text;
}
```

View Controller B:

```
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController
{
@public
    ViewControllerA *refToA;
}
```

Code to launch view controller B from A:

```
ViewControllerB *vc = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
vc->refToA = self;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

in View Controller B set the value:

```
refToA->text = @"text to pass";
[refToA.view addSubview:button];
```

View did appear in A:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if (text != nil)
   {
     NSLog(@"%@", text);
     // create your button here
   }
}
```

Comment: with this i can pass the value from one vc2 to another vc1 but creating a label on vc1 from vc2 is not possible.

Comment: You can. but why you want to create button from vc2?